# Where is it better to wrap a function with try-except?

Tags: python

Next function will fail with some data. Where is it better to wrap it with a try-except block?

```
 if attr in obj_request:
     new_record = GosReestr()
     new_record.display_name_department = request.user.profile_ad.department
     new_record.set_data(**obj_request[attr][_main_data])
     print('before')
     new_record.save()
     print('after')
```

Is this better?

```
 if attr in obj_request:
     new_record = GosReestr()
     new_record.display_name_department = request.user.profile_ad.department
     new_record.set_data(**obj_request[attr][_main_data])
     print('before')
     try:
          new_record.save()
     except as e
     print('after')
```

Or is it better to wrap everything in one `if` block?

Comment: Imo it's better to only wrap the part where the exception you are catching can occure, so the second one is better.

Comment: You shouldn't use bare `except as e` it's better to catch the specific error.

Comment: Where it's "best" to catch exceptions always depends on what you're trying to accomplish. It's impossible to tell from any 10 line snippet: you have to take your application and its concerns into consideration.

Comment: It depends. In some cases you have 10 lines of code where each line can fail with a different exception but you only care whether you can do them all without error or not (and if not do something else), in that case assing `try-except` for each operation is a waste of code. If however you *actualy* handle each exception separately then it's better to handle it in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: I've always found [Exceptions in the rainforest](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/exceptions-in-the-rainforest.html) an enlightening essay about which parts of your code should throw exceptions and which parts should catch them.